# Android app icon with weird blue border at Home Screen

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to learn android app development, I created an android app in android studio and now I want to set my app icon.

I am able to set app icon by following this steps :-

1. Right click on res folder.
2. Select New and Image Assets.
3. Select 512*512 png image from my computer.
4. Adjust size of icon and select background color.
5. And click on Save button.

The above process create my new app icon, everything is okay but I am facing one weird thing. At home scree my icon showing with some blue border, please check this screen shot.

[image]

However it showing correct at application selection screen. Please check this screen shot

[image]

So my simple question is how I remove that blue border from Home Screen ?

Comment: In pixel based devices, recently user or more used app will be shown in suggestion in launcher home screen. It may indicate with Monet color, try adding your app to home screen by drag and drop. Changing wallpaper, will also change the indication circle color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pixel based devices, which comes with preinstalled pixel launcher, there is a feature called App suggestion, It divided into two:

1. Suggestion in Drawer
2. Suggestion in Home screen

When you turned on Suggestion in Home screen, recently used app will be suggested in the home screen, similar to you mention above. That blue colored circle comes from monet color from android 12 feature. If you change the wallpaper it will change the suggestion highlight color too. You can Disable/Enable this setting in Launcher setting.

[For more info on Disable/Enable suggestion follow this guide:](https://www.androidauthority.com/enable-or-disable-app-suggestions-on-google-pixel-3216194/)